# Webpage keeps being redirected to upstream server address after login logout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx

My page keeps redirecting back to my upstream proxy server backend,`https://backend/`, when I want it to redirect back to main page which is `http://localhost/`. How do I redirect it back to localhost? If it helps, I am using proxy pass to direct a Rails server. Any advice would be most welcome.

These are my nginx conf files.

```
upstream backend{
        server localhost:3000;
    }
    server {
        listen       80;
        listen  443 ssl;
        server_name  localhost;
        ssl_certificate localhost.cert;
        ssl_certificate_key localhost.key;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
            proxy_pass http://backend;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Ssl on;
            proxy_set_header origin 'https://backend';
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution was based off this post here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/290141/nginx-reverse-proxy-redirection

> What you're missing are headers that need to be sent to the app. The most important of them is HOST. This shall perform the proxying as desired and shall keep the correct URL in the browser.

```
location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
            proxy_pass http://backend;
            proxy_set_header HOST $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Ssl on;
            proxy_set_header origin 'https://localhost';
        }
```

In the location block, what I added in to solve the issue was `proxy_set_header HOST $host;` and changing the origin to `https://localhost`, which is my HOST page.